# Round decimal values after decimal to lower decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have value in 1200.719994 and I want to convert it to the 1200.71000

how can I get that in sql view, I tried several rounding , ceiling function but i was not able to have it.

can any one help , please

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  ROUND( 1200.719994, 2, 1)
```

returns `1200.710000`. The `1` is the [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-round-to-truncate) parameter, anything other than 0 means truncate, rather than round.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *"ceiling function but i was not able to have it."* `CEILING` is available in **all** supported versions SQL Server; if it's not in the version of SQL Server you have, what version are you using? It was even available in SQL Server 2000.

It's not `CEILING` you're after though, it's `FLOOR`:

```
SELECT FLOOR(1200.719994 * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: Okay , I tried the suggestion given by you but this floor function returns the value 1200.66000. I want to get .719994 to .71000 only

Comment: @PinakKavishwar That query above returns `1200.710000`. Seems you're doing something *else* here. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e69ad4a63a569b52bbd8dd826b07d25)

Comment: Yes , actually If I write this query I get correct .71000 thanks